# Python socket crossplatform EOF error

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am making a program which a client and a server send each other message. I want to make it to be cross platform so a linux os can send messages to windows os and versa visa. In the same platform everything works fine but when I want to send to a different platform I came across to an EOF error.

Server

```
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct

HOST = '192.168.168.116'  # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8889  # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

# Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
    sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')

# Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

# now keep talking with the client

while 1:
    # wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    size = struct.calcsize("L")
    size = conn.recv(size)
    size = socket.ntohl(struct.unpack("L", size)[0])
    buff = ""
    final = ""
    while len(buff) < size:
        buff = conn.recv(size - len(buff))
        final = pickle.loads(buff)
    print(final)
s.close()
```

Client

```
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct


host = '192.168.168.116'
port = 8889
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setblocking(1)
sock.connect((host, port))
names = ["hello", "john", "hi", 55555, "end"]
buffer = pickle.dumps(names)
value = socket.htonl(len(buffer))
size = struct.pack("L", value)
sock.send(size)
sock.send(buffer)
print(buffer)
```

The client runs on ubuntu and the server on windows 10. As i have mention when I execute those scripts in the same platform everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server-side loop is messed up. Assume for the sake of argument that the size of the buffer being sent is 100.

```
buff = ""
final = ""
while len(buff) < size:
    buff = conn.recv(size - len(buff))
    final = pickle.loads(buff)
```

Now let's say your first call to `recv` returns five bytes, so at the end of that statement, the first five bytes of the data are in `buff`. Then you're calling `pickle.loads` on the buffer. But you don't have the entire pickle byte string in your buffer yet, so `loads` raises `EOFError`.

Furthermore, your next iteration of the loop is not *appending* to the current buffer but instead is replacing (overwriting) it. So that if you did get fewer than `size` bytes in the first iteration (and your `loads` weren't already crapping out), you'd never get out of the loop.

Now, why your entire buffer is not getting delivered as a unit is not entirely clear to me (that's not by any means *guaranteed* but usually with a small buffer, it *will* be delivered as a single unit).

Anyway, your receiving loop should look something like this:

```
buff = b""             # For python3, recv returns bytes not str
while len(buff) < size:
    tbuf = conn.recv(size - len(buf))
    if not tbuf:
        raise MyException("Connection closed before all data received")
    buff += tbuf
final = pickle.loads(buff)
```

This way, you're accumulating the buffer through multiple `recv` calls if necessary -- and hence ensure that you've received the entire buffer before you attempt `pickle.loads`.

A few other notes that may be helpful:

1. While, typically, `send` will deliver most short buffers as a unit, that's also not guaranteed. Hence, on the client side, you should use `sendall` to ensure your entire buffer got sent.
2. When using `struct` to serialize data between systems, it's important to specify a byte ordering. If you do not specify one, then the "native" byte ordering for the current platform is used. If the sending system and the receiving system do not agree on that, then the `size` you send will be byte-swapped, which will be nonsensical on the receiving side. You can use whatever byte-ordering you like, but the common convention is to use "network byte-order" (big-endian) between systems. That just means using `struct.pack("!L", value)` -- and the same in `unpack`. (In this case, it's likely that both your ubuntu system and your windows system have the same native byte order so that probably doesn't explain your issue here, but it's best practice to always specify the byte order anyway.)
3. You probably want to use the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option on the *server* side, not the client side. The server side is the one that will be re-using the same port every time you start it. (The client is not `bind`ing hence the OS will choose an unused port for it and you never need the `SO_REUSEADDR` for that.)
4. You don't need to specify an IP address on the server side. If you provide a blank host name (`HOST = ''`), you will be able to `accept` on all valid server IP addresses.